# Require is not defined when importing @project-serum/anchor

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I'm trying to import `@project-serum/anchor` to a Vue 3 project, with

```
import * as anchor from '@project-serum/anchor';
```

The project compiles fine, but when the component loads it throws an error:

```
VM28957:1 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at eval (eval at nodeWrap (sha256.js?6c27:1), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at nodeWrap (sha256.js?6c27:83)
    at createMethod (sha256.js?6c27:67)
    at eval (sha256.js?6c27:501)
    at Object.eval (sha256.js?6c27:518)
    at eval (sha256.js:521)
    at Object../node_modules/js-sha256/src/sha256.js (3.js:1335)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at Module.eval (common.js?789d:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by setting `window.JS_SHA256_NO_NODE_JS = true`